# dpkg: unable to make backup symlink for

Tags: linux, dpkg, chromebook

I'm setting up my new PC by chromebook.
When I do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, this error is occured.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:7.4p1-10+deb9u4) but 1:7.4p1-10+deb9u7 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

1.I do'sudo apt --fix-broken install'.
   Then another error occured in dpkg.

```
The following packages will be upgraded: openssh-server
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/289 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
(Reading database ... 40252 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openssh-server_1%3a7.4p1-10+deb9u7_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking openssh-server (1:7.4p1-10+deb9u7) over (1:7.4p1-10+deb9u4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-    server_1%3a7.4p1-10+deb9u7_arm64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup symlink for './usr/share/man/man5/authorized_keys.5.gz': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-server_1%3a7.4p1-10+deb9u7_arm64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

2.I do `mkdir -r ./usr/share/man/man5`.
  But I cant.

3.I do `ln -s /usr/share/man/man5/authorized_keys.5.gz ./usr/share/man/man5/authorized_keys.5.gz`
  But I cant.

How should I do?? :(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! self solved.

I re-installed dependency packages.

```
sudo apt remove --purge cros-sftp
sudo apt remove --purge cros-guest-tools
apt --fix-broken install
```